# SQL Getting sum of all rows with Inner join and group by

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I am trying to get the sum of rows of the same `DueDate`. I'm joing 2 tables to populate other fields.
However, I'm having difficulty aggregating the values on `Amount` column so that I can end up with one row for a specific `DueDate`
The other columns all have the same value except the `Amount` and `DueDate`.

[image]

Below is my query

```
SELECT
T2.Company,
T2.Code
T2.DueDate,
SUM(T2.Amount)

FROM TBL2 T2 
LEFT JOIN
    TBL1 T1 
    ON T2.Company = T1.Company 
    AND T2.Code IN 
    (
       0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
    )
GROUP BY
T1.Company,T2.Code,T2.DueDate,T2.Amount
```

When I run the query, I get :

[image]

Only the rows with DueDate of '20200604' is aggregated. (5000 + 5000 = 10000).

How do I aggregate and group by when values are different and when there's a table join?

I'd appreciate any help.

Thank you.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of data. [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/5790584)

Comment: @EricBrandt, Sorry about that. I was trying to simplify the resultset and have a long list of fields. I'll keep that in mind. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you just looking for the right aggregation?

```
SELECT T2.Company, T2.Code T2.DueDate, SUM(T2.Amount)
FROM TBL2 T2 LEFT JOIN
     TBL1 T1 
     ON T2.Company = T1.Company AND
        T2.Code IN  0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
GROUP BY T1.Company, T2.Code, T2.DueDate;
```

That is `AMOUNT` does not belong in the `GROUP BY`.

Comment: you solved my problem. Actually, I just simplified the query. It's a long one where I need to group records based on the range of date. For instance, if the age/date is from `20200601` to `20200701`, it must aggregate the rows and SUM only those within the age/date range. Would that follow the same logic as your answer?