# SQL Aggregate records by CASE WHEN

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions, case-when

I am trying to aggregate the records' sum depending on the value that match the `CASE WHEN` 
I am able to aggregate the sum but I don't know how I can group the records depending on the `description` value.

SQL Query:

```
SELECT
T1.Company, T1.DueDate, 
SUM(T1.Amount) AS TotalAmount,

DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) AS Age,
CASE
      WHEN
         DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) <= 0 
      THEN
         'Current'
      WHEN
         DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) > 0 
         AND DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) <= 30 
      THEN
        'Late'
END AS Description

FROM
    Table1 T1 
    LEFT JOIN
      Table2 T2 
      ON T1.Company = T2.Company 
      AND T1.YR = T2.YR 

    INNER JOIN
      Table3 T3 
      ON T1.Company = T3.Company 
      AND T3.YR = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)

GROUP BY T1.Company,T1.DueDate, T3.FromDate
```

My query returns the following.

```
 Company    | DueDate        | TotalAmount | Age  | Description
------------+----------------+-------------+------+------------
 123        | 20200423       |    150      |   7  |   Late
 123        | 20200604       |    18000    |  -35 |   Current
 123        | 20200515       |    500      |  -15 |   Current
```

However, what I really want to accomplish is to aggregate records if they have same `Description` value.
So, the correct result should be :

```
  Company   | TotalAmount  |Description |
------------+--------------+------------+
 123        |     150      |  Late
 123        |     18500    |  Current
```

The 2nd and 3rd row falls under "Current". Therefore, it should combine the 2 rows and add 18000 + 500 = 18500. DueDate and Age column is just for reference. The most important fields are `TotalAmount` and `Description`

I tried grouping by the alias `Description` which is used in `CASE-WHEN` but I didn't work.

I'd appreciate any help.

Thanks!

Comment: This query must have run in MySQL as it should raise several errors! Please tag your DBMS.

Comment: @Parfait: it looks like SQL Server.. except for the use of `current_date`.

Comment: What's the point of the `left join` on `table2`, while it seems this table is not used anywhere in the query?

Comment: @GMB, I thought so too but SQL Server would raise an error of the *description*  and maybe *Age* (if not uniquely captured by *DueDate* and *FromDate*) for not being in `GROUP BY` clause. OP may have remove too much code in posting.

Comment: @GMB There are actually fields I'm using from table2. I just tried to make the query as simple as possible so I removed a few fields. I'll update the question.

Comment: @jordan, please tag your RDBMS and note its version (MySQL 8+ supports CTEs). And re-check your `GROUP BY` clause. Your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61660164/1422451) indicates `mysql`.

Comment: @Parfait It doesn't seem to support CTE. I tried the suggestion from CodeDifferent but editor returned error. I'm doing this on DataLake query editor. I still haven't figured out the version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You copy-and-paste the `CASE` statement into the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
GROUP BY T1.Company, CASE WHEN ...
```

which is a lot of code to repeat.

Or you can use a common table expression (CTE):

```
;WITH
    cte AS 
    (
        SELECT
        T1.Company, T1.DueDate, T1.Amount

        DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) AS Age,
        CASE
            WHEN
                DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) <= 0 
            THEN
                'Current'
            WHEN
                DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) > 0 
                AND DATEDIFF( day, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T1.DueDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112), DATEADD( day, - 1, CONVERT(DATETIME, CAST(T3.FromDate AS VARCHAR(8)), 112) ) ) <= 30 
            THEN
                'Late'
        END AS Description

        FROM
            Table1 T1 
            LEFT JOIN
            Table2 T2 
            ON T1.Company = T2.Company 
            AND T1.YR = T2.YR 

            INNER JOIN
            Table3 T3 
            ON T1.Company = T3.Company 
            AND T3.YR = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE)
    )

SELECT      Company, Description, SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount
FROM        cte
GROUP BY    Company, Description
```

Comment: thanks. I tried copying and pasting `case` statement to the `group by` but it only changed the order of records but didn't combine 2nd and 3rd row. I'm doing this for datalake and I think `cte` isn't supported.

Comment: Did you take `Due Date` and `Age` out of the `GROUP BY` clause?

Comment: It worked this time! It wants both `CASE` statements to be present in the `GROUP-BY` Otherwise, it won't work. Thank you very much! I can sleep now.

Comment: I will update the question details with answer tomorrow. I'm choosing your answer the best answer. I appreciate the help.